# display data based on users login using php mysql in flutter

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I want to display the user profile data from table users. This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

   include ("connect.php");

   //$username = $_POST['username'];

   $response = array();

   $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT agentName, agentCode, agentId FROM users WHERE username ='$username'");

   while ($a = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){


       $b['agentName'] = $a['agentName'];
       $b['agentCode'] = $a['agentCode'];
       $b['agentId'] = $a['agentId'];

       array_push($response, $b);

   }
   echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

but it does not display, but when I change the username with a specific username, the data will display. Is there any problem with my code?

[This is the result for the coding above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ0f9.png)

The data will display in

```
_lihatUser() async {
    list.clear();
    setState(() {
        loading=true;
    });

    final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.userData);
    if (response.contentLength==2){
    }else{
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        data.forEach((api){
            final ab = new userModel(
                api['agentCode'],
                api['agentId'],
                api['agentName']
            );
            list.add(ab);
        });
        setState(() {
            loading=false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell the condition (apecific username) where the data display for you ?

Comment: I just edit the question